# why does this elif statement return a syntax error?

Tags: python

the error says

```
File "Scantron.py", line 28

    elif len(test_answers) != len(test_key):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Command exited with non-zero status 1

```
def grade_scantron(test_answers, test_key):
    right = 0
    for i in test_answers:
        if test_answers[i] == test_key[i]:
            right += 1
        return right
        elif len(test_answers) != len(test_key):
            return -1
```

Comment: indent line 27, `return right` within the if loop `if test_answers[i] == test_key[i]:`

Comment: Please add more context to the code, I think you should add the whole if statement. And format your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The `elif` statement after you `return right` from a function won't work and hence the error.
You have to edit your code and indent your `return right` inside the `if` statement:

```
def grade_scantron(test_answers, test_key):
    right = 0
    for i in test_answers:
        if test_answers[i] == test_key[i]:
            right += 1
            return right                  # change here
        elif len(test_answers) != len(test_key):
            return -1
```